# how to randomise the image shown in a sketchpad

Tags: python, random

I really appreciate any responses. I am thoroughly confused and never knew this experiment design/builder software was so complicated!
I am a fast learner, but still a newbie so please be patient.
Yes I have googled the answers for my question but no answers to similar questions seem to work.

I have an experiment, there are 8 conditions,
each condition needs to show 1 image, chosen at random from a folder of similar images.
Each trial needs to be different (so each participant sits a differently ordered set of conditions) AND each condition's selected image will be different.

So;
Condition- Image
A        - 1 to 140
B        - 1 to 80
etc..

Recording data is not a problem as this can be done by hand, but I just need the images to be randomly selected from a pre-defined group.

I have tried using code to randomise and shuffle the order, but have got nowhere.
Please help,
Tom

Comment: So where exactly are you tripping up? The displaying of the images, or the generation of the random image?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and what specific problems you're having. Your question is too vague to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To generate retrieve the path of a random image in a folder `img_folder`, it's not too difficult. You can use `img_path_array = os.listdir('.../img_folder')`. Randomly generate an integer between `0` and `len(img_path_array)` using `random_index = randrange(len(img_path_array))` (import `random` to use this function), and gain access to the random file url by calling `img_path_array[random_index]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things to do: randomize the order of a pool of 8 things some number of times, and make sure that none of the permutations are chosen more than once.

I'll start by pointing out that hopefully you have fewer than `factorial(8)` participants, because that is the maximum number of unique arrangements.

Here is the brute-force approach which generates *all* of the possible arrangements of your input list (`images`), then shuffles it; you can then just take the first *n* arrangements which are guaranteed to be unique.

```
import itertools
import random

#images is a list of your images
orderings = list(itertools.permutations(images))
random.shuffle(orderings)
#now just take top n elements of orderings
```

Now I'll again point out that this is fine for when you have 8 conditions; 8! is only 40320, which is fine to keep in memory.  For basically anything larger than 10 conditions you're going to want to take a more sophisticated approach.